# How do i use class weight in tensorflow 2 for multi label binary classification?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.x

The problem is that I only found the example for one label binary classification in the TensorFlow 2 doc.

```
# Scaling by total/2 helps keep the loss to a similar magnitude.
# The sum of the weights of all examples stays the same.
weight_for_0 = (1 / neg)*(total)/2.0 
weight_for_1 = (1 / pos)*(total)/2.0

class_weight = {0: weight_for_0, 1: weight_for_1}

print('Weight for class 0: {:.2f}'.format(weight_for_0))
print('Weight for class 1: {:.2f}'.format(weight_for_1))
```

[sample reference from doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data)

The solution I have already try is using list of class_weight, dict of class_weight and array of class_weight.
I would like to know if there is a way to inject multi-label binary classification class weight into the fit() of TensorFlow 2

example of what I have try

```
import numpy as np
# list of  duct
[{0: 0.474964234620887, 1: 0.525035765379113},{0: 0.48783977110157367, 1: 0.5121602288984263},{0: 0.5135908440629471, 1: 0.4864091559370529},{0: 0.46494992846924177, 1: 0.5350500715307582}]
# dict of dict
{0: {0: 0.474964234620887, 1: 0.525035765379113},
 1: {0: 0.48783977110157367, 1: 0.5121602288984263},
 2: {0: 0.5135908440629471, 1: 0.4864091559370529},
 3: {0: 0.46494992846924177, 1: 0.5350500715307582}}
# array of dict
np.asarray([{0: 0.474964234620887, 1: 0.525035765379113},
            {0: 0.48783977110157367, 1: 0.5121602288984263},
            {0: 0.5135908440629471, 1: 0.4864091559370529},
            {0: 0.46494992846924177, 1: 0.5350500715307582}])
```